# Find and replace text in Illustrator using Apple script

Tags: replace, automation, applescript, batch-processing, adobe-illustrator

I am using the current version of Illustrator CC. I would like the ability to find and replace 5 instances/frames of text within an Illustrator or EPS file. Maybe a drag and drop type of script that executes a prompt for a find and replace field?
Is this possible? Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: See https://forums.adobe.com/thread/858021 (works with CS4; I'd be willing to bet it works with latest CC, too -- sorry, I can't test that right now)

Answer (score 0):

SO's for getting help with your own code. For requesting scripts, try Adobe's [Illustrator Scripting](https://forums.adobe.com/community/illustrator/illustrator_scripting) forum.